# Where do I need to call CoInitialize in the C++ REST SDK?

Tags: c++, rest, com, casablanca

I need to call some COM APIs from a simple REST server using the [REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk). It's similar to the [BlackJack sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/tree/master/Release/samples/BlackJack/BlackJack_Server).

Whenever I try to create a COM object I get an exception that `CoInitialize` has not been called. But where exactly can I initialize the thread that processes the REST request? I couldn't find any documentation.

I tried the constructor (BlackJackDealer in the sample) but that does not work:

```
BlackJackDealer::BlackJackDealer(utility::string_t url) : m_listener(url)
{
  CoInitialize(0);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks in the C++ REST SDK execute on the Windows Threadpool by default. Instead of trying to join threadpool threads to an STA (which should be considered an anti-pattern), you can either:

- Specify a custom scheduler (deriving from `pplx::scheduler_interface`) when creating tasks that need to call COM methods. See `pplxinterface.h` for the interface declaration and `windows_scheduler::schedule()` inside `pplxwin.cpp` for how the default scheduler is implemented on various Windows flavors.
- Manually marshall any COM interactions to a thread that you own and control (and have called `CoInitialize` on). This probably means something like having a global vector of `std::function` objects that you protect with the usual `mutex`/`condition_variable` dance.

You may need to perform manual marshalling even if you go the custom scheduler route, but the custom scheduler will interoperate better with the existing task-based APIs.